# VBAloop if array equal then highlight row

Tags: excel, vba

[image]
[image]

What I am trying to do is that if the ID in ws2 is same to array in ws1, then highlight the lines. what should I modify?

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim i, i2 As Long
Dim LastRow, LastRow2 As Long
    
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("ws1")

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("ws2")

    With ws1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    With ws2
        LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For i2 = 1 To LastRow2
            If ws1.Range("A" & i).Value = ws2.Range("D" & i2).Value Then
                ws2.Range("D" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            End If
        Next
    Next




End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to modify? - What's wrong with your codes output?

Comment: Assuming you just want to highlight the ws2 rows just change the `i` to `i2` in the line `ws2.Range("D" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37`. I would also add directly under that line a `Exit For` (above the last End If) which will help prevent unnecessary looping. Only add that if there are no duplicates though.

Comment: Why are you not using a VLookup in a conditional formatting rule? No need for VBA code.

Comment: Thank you @Simon, this really solved my problem.

Comment: @FunThomas because I always need to do this thing, so I'm thinking to make it automated.

Comment: @Gunhanwei: you can automate conditional formatting :-)